# No feedback when hitting post flag rate limits

Tags: bug, review-queues, flags, low-quality-posts, rate-limiting

I was going through the Help & Improvement queue today and flagging 98% of the posts as low quality, as usual<sup>*</sup>.

Anyway, when I was clicking Ok on the JavaScript alert, sometimes it was just closing without anything happening. Firing up my browser's network inspector, I could see the server responding with 409 and a response body saying "You may only flag a post every 5 seconds."

But, no indication of this error was provided on the front end.

Firefox 71.0b9, no JS errors showing on the console.

---

<sup><sub><sup>*</sup>I remain hopeful that one day I will go in and find it full of questions that actually need editing...</sub></sup>

Comment: When you flag a post in LQP, does it mark the review item as completed for you? Or do you still have to click an "I'm done" button to move to the next post?

Comment: When I haven't hit the rate limit, it marks the review as skipped and moves on to the next review.