# Review queues are not working for me (only me?)

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, review-suspension

I've been having trouble with review queues, and not long ago I was banned from them because of the Triage ["Requires editing" issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372485/the-incorrect-usage-of-requires-editing-is-still-causing-problems-can-we-do-s), a few days after the ban lift I got my flags suspended because of things like [this "not an answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52098214/kube-flannel-in-crashloopbackoff-status/63105603#63105603), which is clearly a comment to another answer, but we cannot now which because it was posted as a separate answer, or [this "low quality"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559035/how-to-rotate-a-video-with-opencv/63105766#63105766).

So now without flags I head back to the late answers queue and I get [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/26840109) and I think ok, maybe I'm being too hard and this answer is definitely better than the declined low quality I just mentioned. I get banned for more than two weeks because it was an audit and I did not flagged low quality.

So, the first thing is that I think if you cannot flag you should also be suspended from the review queues. I noticed I was suspended from Triage, but flags are required in every queue. In retrospective it does not make sense to me to go into Late Answers without being able to flag "not an answer".

Second, and my main point, maybe reviews are a bit too hard for "newcomers" like me, I have been reading more and more meta recently and I still get these bans because I don't seem to understand how these queues work, and also by reading the meta I realize it is not just me, but a lot of people in my position.

I also read a lot not to be discouraged by these bans, but it is actually frustrating. I don't think I will be reviewing any more, not because I'm mad or anything, but because I ultimately come here to help and I can see I'm not helping there.

I wouldn't want to end this without suggesting something, but not a lot of things come to mind. I think it's really an issue of consistency across the platform, and I don't think I know enough about it to suggest a course of action.

Comment: Firstly, I disagree with the first NAA flag you posted here. It's not the best answer, but it is an answer. A comment asks for clarification, and that's not a comment. Downvote the answer if you don't like it.

Comment: Secondly, you can learn about the review queues by looking through the guidance for each queue. For instance, here is the [guidance for the suggested edits review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/500111).

Comment: Lastly, you shouldn't be reviewing when you are flag banned. If something requires a flag, but you can't flag, then **_skip_**!

Comment: Thanks for the guidance tip, those are not easy to find if you don't know what you're looking for. I have to disagree on the first point though, how can an answer begin with "and also" without referencing anything? from [deleted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are: commentary on the question or other answers"

Comment: You are currently not flag banned. Note that a review ban applies to **all** review queues, not to just one queue at a time.

Comment: If an Answer can be edited to be OK and understandable, then it's an Answer. The "And also ensure.." can be edited into "Ensure.." :) These should get you some more clarity on the "Not an Answer" flag: [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552) and [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370). Some say that an Answer is an attempt if it can answer **any** Question, not isolated to the one it's posted under.

Comment: That...actually is a fairly bad audit.  Audits are supposed to be obvious, and an answer describing a solution to a problem (update the software)—albeit describing it poorly—probably should not be an audit.  It's honestly debatable whether that answer should have even been removed.

Comment: @RyanM I do agree with that, so I'll be adding a [tag:disputed-review-audit] to the question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was at the time of the review ban, a couple of days ago. I also couldn't get into Triage, which I assumed it was because of the flags. At least this time I have a notice in review queues which I didn't have the last time, it was an issue last time not knowing I was banned but now it's solved.

Comment: @vlizana - You really should get in the habit of opening and reviewing the actual question in another tab while you perform your reviews.  As others have pointed out audits are suppose to be obvious, but in the case of a bad audit, looking at the actual question helps a great deal.  If you need assistance choosing the correction action when performing a review you really should seek out that assistance before make a final decision.  **If you have any doubts just skip the review.**

Comment: @SecurityHound I don't understand this. If it is an audit and I open the question on another tab I will know it's an audit and also what I have to do to pass (e.g. if it shows 0 votes on the audit but -5 on the actual question, I will know I have to flag). Isn't this against the audit's purpose?

Comment: Audit is to make sure your not a robot and you are actually reviewing contributions.  If you always do that, or only when your not sure, your actually fulfilling the purpose of the audit.  You can’t actually cheat the audit, it’s a test your suppose to pass, unless your NOT paying attention.

Answer (score 5):

> So, first thing is that I think if you cannot flag you should also be suspended from the review queues, I noticed I was suspended from Triage but flags are required in every queue, in retrospective it does not make sense to me to go into Late Answers without being able to flag "not an answer".

Yes, you're absolutely right.

No one has any business working through the review queues if they can't raise any flags. The vast majority of posts in the review queues *need to be flagged*. About the only correct action you can take in the review queues when you don't have any flags is to "Skip".

Please consider either turning this into a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) or posting a new question with that tag.

> Second, and my main point, maybe reviews are a bit too hard for "newcommers" like me…

Reviewing is optional and a privilege. If you don't feel prepared and/or aren't confident that you can make the correct decision, then don't do it.

Reviewing isn't something that we can just arbitrarily make easier. It serves a very real and practical purpose: improving the quality of content on this site. We need help with it, but we need *accurate* help. Inaccurate reviews are more harmful than helpful.

> I think it's really an issue of consistency across the platform

I don't know what consistency (or lack thereof) you are referring to here.

Comment: related feature request and bug report seem to be [No feedback when hitting post flag rate limits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391459/839601) at MSO and [Block First Post and Late Answer reviews when you can’t flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333059/165773) at MSE

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, what I consider inconsistent is flagging an answer, getting the flag declined and failing an audit afterwards because of not flagging a similar answer.